# SQL Server Procedure Parameter Null Case

Tags: sql-server-2008, null, case

I have a single int output parameter for a sproc in MSSQL 2008. The value can be null or it can be populated.

I am trying to write a clever single select statement that will return one row:
if the param value is populated, return that row
if the param value is null, return the top 1 row where issoftdeleted=0

Thanks for all ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
   TOP (CASE WHEN @param IS NULL THEN 2000000000 ELSE 1 END)
  ...
FROM
   Mytable
WHERE
   SomeID = @param
   OR 
   (@param IS NULL AND issoftdeleted = 0)
ORDER BY
   something --to make the top meaningful
```

If you expect one row when @param is set then use TOP (1)

Personally, I'd consider using an IF statement and 2 separate SELECTs...